# Namespace name in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++-cli

I am trying to create a namespace in c++ in the following way:

```
namespace MyCompany.Library.Myproduct {

public ref class ClassWrapper
{

};
 }
```

I am getting error:

```
  Error 1   error C2059: syntax error : '.' ClassWrapper.h  7   1    MyCompany.Library.Myproduct
```

Why can not I have . in namespace?

### Edit1

This namespace definition is in a c++/cli and would be used in c# code. in C# this namespace is valid, but it seems it is not valid in c++. How can define c# compatible namespaces in c++/cli code?

Comment: One of the first links I saw on Googling "namespace C++" has your answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx

Comment: You can have a namespace in a namespace instead though.

Comment: @chris But it did not say that . in namespace Is not allowed. The above namespace is valid in c#.

Comment: Well, it did say you can't have compound names for namespaces. It shouldn't matter what character joins them with that, though it's :: in C++, not ., which is right there later in the same bottom code.

Comment: Dot is not allowed in identifiers. Period.

Comment: Could you make your question more readable?

Answer (score 8):

You're not allowed to use the dot in namespace name. However, you can have nested namespaces.

```
namespace Boap
{
  namespace Lib
  {
    namespace Prod
    {
      class Llama
      {
      public:
        Llama()
        {
          std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
```

And instanciate your llama this way:

```
Boap::Lib::Prod::Llama l;
```

AFAIK namespace and classname follow the same namming rules than variables.
A variable's name cannot start with a numeric character, and the same apply to class / namespace's names. The same goes for ".".

EDIT: The following is pure assumptions, because I have no knowledge of C# or windows CLI.
Does it make sense that a nested namespace in C++ (eg Boap::Lib) would be translated into Boap.Lib in C#? *Maybe* it's just as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Now, in 2023 it is possible to achieve what you want; with `::`. You need to make sure the `C++ Language Standard` is set to at least `C++17`.

Then this code would compile and work:

```
    namespace MyCompany::Library::Myproduct {
        public class ClassWrapper
        {
        };
    }
```

Comment: `public class` is invalid.